# C# -export datagridview to excel with leading zero in c#

Tags: c#

While exporting the datagridview to Excel in C#.net ,leading zeros are missing.
For example : Data in the cell is "001693"
After exporting to excel it is displaying me like this "1693".
Please help me out of this.
this is my code;

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;

            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
            for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            var saveFileDialoge = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialoge.FileName = "output";
            saveFileDialoge.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
            if (saveFileDialoge.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialoge.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Are you able to set the data type of the cell to "text" or set a specific format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set text format to cell where you want to save number with leading zeroes.
In this sample I add code which set text format for entire row to speed up processing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    (worksheet.Rows[i+2 + ":" + i+2, System.Reflection.Missing.Value] as Excel.Range).NumberFormat = "@";
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```